# swiping images between span on click using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zrqjLrjf/

html code :

```
<div class="ListViewLayout_dv">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="swipeDisplay('list')" id="lb_ListView"  title="List" style="position: relative;top: 3px;"><span class="grid-listView1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a> &nbsp;
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="swipeDisplay('grid')" id="A1"  title="Grid" style="position: relative;top: 3px;"><span class="grid-GridView">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a> 
</div>
```

script :

```
 function swipeDisplay(view) {
        if (view == "list") {
            $(".grid-listView1").each(function () {
                $(this).removeAttr("class");
                $(this).addClass("grid-listView");
            });
            $(".grid-GridView1").each(function () {
                $(this).removeAttr("class");
                $(this).addClass("grid-GridView");
            });
        }
        else {
              $(".grid-GridView").each(function () {
                $(this).removeAttr("class");
                $(this).addClass("grid-GridView1");
            });
        }
    }
```

I am having a problem swiping between images when clicking on them , what i want to do basically is when i click on the `list` image it should get unfocused and the grid image should be focused and vise-versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are :)

```js
function swipeDisplay(view) {
  if (view == "list") {
    $(".grid-listView").each(function() {
      $(this).removeAttr("class");
      $(this).addClass("grid-listView1");
    });
    $(".grid-GridView1").each(function() {
      $(this).removeAttr("class");
      $(this).addClass("grid-GridView");
    });
  } else {
    $(".grid-GridView").each(function() {
      $(this).removeAttr("class");
      $(this).addClass("grid-GridView1");
    });

    $(".grid-listView1").each(function() {
      $(this).removeAttr("class");
      $(this).addClass("grid-listView");
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.grid-listView {
  background: url(http://www.ishtari.com/catalog/view/theme/marketshop/image/list-icon.png) left -68px no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
}
.grid-listView1 {
  background: url(http://www.ishtari.com/catalog/view/theme/marketshop/image/list-icon.png) left -45px no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
}
.grid-GridView {
  background: url(http://www.ishtari.com/catalog/view/theme/marketshop/image/list-icon.png) left -23px no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
}
.grid-GridView1 {
  background: url(http://www.ishtari.com/catalog/view/theme/marketshop/image/list-icon.png) left top no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
}
.ListViewLayout_dv {
  position: relative;
  left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ListViewLayout_dv">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="swipeDisplay('list')" id="lb_ListView" title="List" style="position: relative;top: 3px;"><span class="grid-listView1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a> &nbsp;
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="swipeDisplay('grid')" id="A1" title="Grid" style="position: relative;top: 3px;"><span class="grid-GridView">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Glad that I could help. Now you can accept the answer so the question can be closed :)

Comment: yes of course i am just waiting for the time counter to be available so i can accept

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function swipeDisplay(view) {
    if (view == "list") {
        $(".grid-listView1").each(function () {
            $(this).removeAttr("class");
            $(this).addClass("grid-listView");
        });
        $(".grid-GridView1").each(function () {
            $(this).removeAttr("class");
            $(this).addClass("grid-GridView1");
        });
    }
    else {
          $(".grid-GridView").each(function () {
            $(this).removeAttr("class");
            $(this).addClass("grid-GridView1");
        });

          $(".grid-listView1").each(function () {
              $(this).removeAttr("class");
              $(this).addClass("grid-listView");
          });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example, without using any script, actually its a work around.

```css
input[id^=list],
input[id^=grid] {
  display: none;
}
input[id^=list] + label,
input[id^=grid] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}
input[id^=grid] + label {
  background: url('http://www.ishtari.com/catalog/view/theme/marketshop/image/list-icon.png');
  background-position-y: 63px;
}
input[id^=list] + label {
  background: url('http://www.ishtari.com/catalog/view/theme/marketshop/image/list-icon.png');
  background-position-y: 18px;
}
input[id^=grid]:checked + label {
  background: url('http://www.ishtari.com/catalog/view/theme/marketshop/image/list-icon.png');
  background-position-y: 86px;
}
input[id^=list]:checked + label {
  background: url('http://www.ishtari.com/catalog/view/theme/marketshop/image/list-icon.png');
  background-position-y: 41px;
}
```

```html
<input type='radio' name='view' id='list1' checked="checked" />
<label for='list1'></label>
<input type='radio' name='view' id='grid1' />
<label for='grid1'></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using jQuery already, then I guess you don't need to write a long code to achieve the same solution. You can use the below code incase, if you want to optimize it:
- You can remove the `onclick` attribute on the `html` tags and have it bind from jquery itself for loose binding:

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="ListViewLayout_dv">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="lb_ListView" title="List" style="position: relative;top: 3px;"><span class="grid-listView selected">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a> &nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="lb_GridView" title="Grid" style="position: relative;top: 3px;"><span class="grid-GridView">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a> 
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.grid-listView {
    background: url(http://www.ishtari.com/catalog/view/theme/marketshop/image/list-icon.png) 0 -68px no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
}
.grid-listView.selected {
    background: url(http://www.ishtari.com/catalog/view/theme/marketshop/image/list-icon.png) 0 -45px no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
}
.grid-GridView {
  background: url(http://www.ishtari.com/catalog/view/theme/marketshop/image/list-icon.png) 0 -23px no-repeat;
  display:inline-block;
}
.grid-GridView.selected {
  background: url(http://www.ishtari.com/catalog/view/theme/marketshop/image/list-icon.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  display:inline-block;
}
.ListViewLayout_dv {
    position: relative;
    left: 8px;
}
```

**JS Code:**

```
$("#lb_ListView, #lb_GridView").on("click", "span", function(){
    $("span").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```